# I need to draw this

Tags: draw

I need to draw in particular these diagrams

[image: Figure 1]

and

[image: Figure 2]

Does anybody want to help?

Also, I know that Tikz is the best "tool" or way to do these things. Is there exist a way to generate a latex code by drawing in some program? I saw only LatexDraw, but I found it a bit poor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ops, I should have read the comments before I wrote the code. So I stop here and find it more interesting to look at the pgfmanual than to write such comments.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shadings,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (0,0) coordinate (O) --
(9,0) coordinate (R) -- (9,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[very thick] (O) -- (R);
\draw[ultra thick] (1,4) coordinate(T) to[out=-50,in=180] (3,2) coordinate (M)
to (5,2) coordinate (E);
\draw[<->,dashed] (O) -- (O|-E) node[midway,left]{H};
\draw[<->,dashed] (O|-T) -- (O|-E) node[midway,left]{h};
\draw[-]  ([xshift=-1mm]O|-E) --(E) node[pos=0.7,below=0.3cm,text width=2cm,
align=right] (ponto) {ponto de arremesso};
\draw[-]  ([xshift=-1mm]O|-T) --(T);
\shade[ball color=gray] ([xshift=1mm,yshift=1mm]T) circle ({sqrt(2)*1mm});
(B2) to[out=0,in=125] (7,{0.2*sqrt(2)});
\draw[shift=(E),thick,-latex,dashed,] plot[variable=\x,samples=50,domain=0:3]
({\x},{-1.87*\x*\x/9+0.1*sqrt(2)});
\shade[ball color=gray] ([xshift=-sqrt(2)*1mm,yshift=sqrt(2)*1mm]E)  circle ({sqrt(2)*1mm});
\shade[ball color=gray] (8.1,{0.1*sqrt(2)})  circle ({sqrt(2)*1mm});
\draw[-latex](E)--++(0.5,0) node[below] {x};
\draw[-latex](E)--++(0,-0.5) node[left] {z};
\draw[-latex,dashed,shorten >=1pt](ponto)--(E);
\node[above=4mm of T] (partida) {ponto de partida};
\draw[-latex,dashed,shorten >=1pt] (partida) to[bend right] (T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Made the trajectory more realistic (and added a few features).